# How to create a C# library to be used from C# projects?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to develop a small library which will be used across different C# projects.

I was looking at this guide - https://github.com/LRPalacios/net-core-get-started

It talks about creating a Class Library (.NET Core).

However, my copy Visual Studio Community 2015 does not show this option at all.

Only relevant thing I see is Windows Desktop -> Classic Desktop -> Class Library [image: Windows Desktop -> Classic Desktop -> Class Library].

What is the difference and what is the best way to create a class library for use across different C# projects. My library won't have any UI elements.

Also, is dll the only way to go - is there a concept of static libs in dotnet?

Comment: "across different C# projects" - how different is "different" (like UWP vs. Desktop, Desktop vs. .Net Core, ...)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - There are 3 types - ASP.net, native console applications & native applications with a UI.

Comment: Did you install the .net Core as per the instructions on that page?

Comment: @tinstaafl - I did - anyway let me try to uninstall and reinstall - however, what's the difference between a class library and a .NET (Core) library?

Comment: On the web page you referenced, in the screenshot it shows, there is description of what the .netCore class library does.  It creates a class library as a Nuget package that can be target any platform.

Comment: @user93353 i suggest reading

https://www.excella.com/insights/demystifying-key-differences-in-net-core-1-0-vs-net-framework

Comment: @tinstaafl - is that necessary for me - my library will be used only on Windows Desktop or Windows Server - it will be used in a ASP.NET project and some native applications

Comment: To answer your question .NET Core executes code on a different runtime to regular .NET.  If you're just starting, it's a good time to learn .NET Core, however you should be aware that at this time the road to mastering .NET Core as opposed to the regular .NET Framework is a lot bumpier.  The tooling and support for the regular .NET framework is a lot more mature and easier to work with.

Comment: You'll have to try it and test it to be sure, but if I'm not mistaken a standard .net class library should work in any .net project as long as it's targeting Windows.

Comment: @Mick - Looking to develop something quickly - not much of a dotnet guy - I am a C++/Java programmer. I have webservices written in Java - I am trying to write a quick wrapper library which will do some initialisation and then call the services & then do some post processing and return stuff to the C# projects - I don't think it will be more than a 2 day effort - I guess I am better off doing a regular class library rather than a .NET code library. Also is there a concept of a static lib (.lib in C++ or jar in Java) - or is my output always going to be a dll?

Comment: @user93353 if you need to call service from C# project going for native (C++) library/DLL via interop would likely be well over your head... I'd recommend to follow Mick's recommendation and stick with regular .Net (ASP.Net / classic desktop) - unless your site already build with ASP.Net core.

Comment: For the three project types you outlined I would go with the regular class library, not the .NET core one. If you later on need to target IoT devices, mobile units via Xamarin, etc. then you can delve into the .NET Core world at that point.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the .Net core project type issue, you have to install Visual Studio Update 3 and then install .Net Core Tools for Visual Studio.

You can of course use the current Class Library project but this will work only against the Full .Net framework project not .Net core alone